# C++ | LNK1104 - cannot open file kernel32.lib

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio

I have a problem when I try to build my C++ console application with Visual Studio. Every time I get the error: `LNK1104 - cannot open file kernel32.lib`

I'm starting to learn C++ by using a tutorial so I'm very new to this. I've tried some things I found on Google and I tried to retype all of my code.

I'm still not sure how to fix this problem. I hope that someone can help me.

Thanks,

Comment: ***I tried to retype all of my code*** Your code is not the problem. Your problem is with the installation of Visual Studio. Perhaps you selected a x64 build and only have the 32 bit sdk installed.

Comment: Is this global or project specific? When I make a simple new project that just prints some text it works fine without errors.

Comment: I think it is both. Project specific settings can override the global settings. To me it looks like the answer is on the right path with the new information that you just added in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Check the VC++ directories, in VS 2010 these can be found in your project properties. Check whether $(WindowsSdkDir)\lib is included in the directories list, if not, manually add it. If you're building for X64 platform, you should select X64 from the “Platform” ComboBox, and make sure that $(WindowsSdkDir)\lib\x64 is included in the directories list.

Comment: Is this global or project specific? When I make a simple new project that just prints some text it works fine without errors.